# background-image : url() not working in typescript?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, typescript

In my rails project I try to hide and show an image when a user click on it, here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#myvideo").prop('muted', true)){
    $("#mute").css("background-image","asset_url(mute.svg)");
  }

$("#mute").click( function (){
  if( $("#myvideo").prop('muted') ) {
    $("#myvideo").prop('muted', false);
    $("#mute").css("background-image","url(app/assets/icons/speaker.svg)");
  } else {
    $("#myvideo").prop('muted', true);
    $("#mute").css("background-image","url('mute.svg')");
  }
});
});
```

none of this try works but when I put an url like  `$("#mute").css("background-image","url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/170684/mute-volume-control.svg)");` it's ok,

Edit : also tried :

```
$("#mute").css("background-image","url(<%= asset_path 'mute.svg' %>)");
```

but it doesn't work

Anyone knows why ? And how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move/copy mute.svg inside **app/assets/images** folder, and you acccess it with this code below

```
$("#mute").css("background-image","url('/assets/mute.svg')"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple as you think.

You need load images from server with `asset_path`.

See docs here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

If this works for you thats mean you've problem in your image path

```
$("#mute").css("background-image","url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/170684/mute-volume-control.svg)");
```

there two ways:
get your app path by `asset_path` then

```
$("#mute").css("background-image","url("+YOUR_ASSET_PATH+"assets/icons/speaker.svg)");
```

OR try

```
$("#mute").css("background-image","url(/assets/icons/speaker.svg)");
```

Comment: nope it doesn't work, I can see the path in my console but nothing is displaying